# Верифицировать почту пользователя в RESTful приложении, чтобы аккаунт был недоступным для других пользователей до завершения верификации?

Tags: php, rest, клиент-сервер, authenticationtoken, verification

Очень легко создать нового пользователя с помощью HTTP запроса на `/users` с методом POST, затем сохранить его в таблицу, в которой users имеют столбец на подобии `is_verified`, который сразу после создания будет `false`. А затем отправить на почту письмо со ссылкой, которая содержит токен, нажав на которую пользователь инициирует GET запрос на адрес `/users/is_verified/{token}` где будет происходить сравнение токенов и в случае совпадения произойдёт изменение столбца `is_verified` на `true`. Да, это уже не RESTful, ведь GET запрос не должен менять состояние данных на сервере, но иногда приходится идти на жертвы, к тому же я видел случаи где разработчики похуже забивают на рекомендации.

В этом способе самый большой минус - это то, что созданный объект User, который еще не верифицирован, сохраняется в базу данных.

Во-первых, пользователь может войти в систему, хотя я не хочу чтобы так было, поэтому нужно найти способ запретить это.

Во-вторых, когда клиент будет запрашивать пользователя/пользователей, то он может спокойно получить неверифицированных пользователей и обрабатывать их так будто они полноправные пользователи, а я хочу чтобы неверифицированных пользователей **небыло видно нигде**. Запретить это нужно на сервере, а это значит, что мне придётся в каждом из методов репозитория, которые возвращают пользователя/пользователей(а таких может быть много), добавлять условие `where 'is_verified' = 'true'`, короче говоря заниматься дублированием, а это мне абсолютно не нравится.

Так вот, ответа на вторую проблему я нигде не нашел. 
У меня есть другая идея: неверифицированный объект User можно сохранить в другую таблицу, а после завершения верификации эмейла переместить в основную. Мне один человек сказал, что это дичь, но я сомневаюсь в его адекватности и проффесионализме. Также я нашел в интернете пару ответов на подобный вопрос, но почему-то большинству нравится подход с столбцом типа `is_verified`, **хотя никто не упоминает о его минусах**.

Посоветуйте лучшее решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: если не хотите в необходимые запросы дописывать `is_verified`, то создайте представление, которое выбирает таковых, и работайте с ним. а так-то вы еще в каждом методе репозитрия, возвращающего пользователей, будете писать например `select id, name` и `from users`, это-то вы дублированием не считаете? имхо, вы придумали себе проблему на пустом месте. У вас кстати кроме верификации могут появится еще и какие-нибудь флаги `active/blocked` и их тоже придется учитывать в запросах.

Comment: а если так печетесь о том, чтобы get-запрос не изменил единожды не изменил данные, то отправьте пользователя на страницу. где он нажмет кнопку и выполнит post-запрос.